# Setting event's parameter value at declaration time in PyQT5?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt5

## Background

I'm writing a simple application in PyQT5. The main `QWidget` is a `QGridLayout`, and visually the result should be something like this:

```
        +-----------------------------------+
row1    |  QLabelA  |  QLabelB  |  QLabelC  |
        +-----------------------------------+
row2    |  QLabelA  |  QLabelB  |  QLabelC  |
        +-----------------------------------+
row3    |  QLabelA  |  QLabelB  |  QLabelC  |
        +-----------------------------------+
        ...
```

This `QGridLayout` is filled using a loop where each iteration represents a row, so I have something like this:

```
row = 0
self.grid = QGridLayout()

while row < 10:
    filepath = 'icon.png'
    icon = QImage(filepath)
    QLabelA = QLabel()
    QLabelA.setPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(icon))

    QLabelB = QLabel()
    QLabelB.setPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(icon))

    QLabelC = QLabel()
    QLabelC.setPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(icon))

    self.grid.addWidget(QLabelA, row, 0)
    self.grid.addWidget(QLabelB, row, 1)
    self.grid.addWidget(QLabelC, row, 2)

    row += 1
```

So far, this works quite well.

## The problem

My aim is to make that each of these `QLabel`s, which visually are images, have an associated action that should be triggered after a user's simple click over each of them. For that, I found [a property](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qlabel.html#mousePressEvent) that allows calling a method after clicking over an object, so I could simply do this:

```
QLabelA.mousePressedEvent = this.do_something

def do_something(self, event):
    ...
```

The first problem is easy to see: I need a method to identify which of the `QLabel`s has been clicked (i.e., which row). For that, I found a way to add custom parameters to the `mousePressedEvent`. Let's focus on the `QLabelA` fields which will call the `clicked()` method on click:

```
QLabelA.mousePressEvent = lambda x: self.clicked(row)

def clicked(self, row):
    print row
```

Here comes the big problem: Each of these `QLabelA` fields are dependent on the `row` variable and they are not evaluated at creation time, but at click time instead. Thus, if the user clicks on `QLabelA` at row 0, inside the `clicked()` method, `row` will have the last `row` value (i.e., the number of rows of the `QGridLayout`) instead of the one that had at definition time. If `self.grid` has 5 rows, it doesn't matter where the user clicks, `row` will always have a value of 5.

I tried workarounding this limitation by defining a list with the `row` value inside, but it made no difference since it is still dependent on the `row` value at click time.

## Question

Is there a way to make this work as intended and assign the value passed to the `click()` method at creation time instead of click time? Any different approach or way to achieve this are also welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're rather close to a solution with your lambda x: statement, you're just missing one little piece

## Using Lambdas to store transient values

Since your `row` variable changes a lot, you need to store the value when the function is created; your `self.clicked` references the current `row`, as you notice yourself. To help that, you can change your lambda like so:

```
# current: x is the event, row is looked up when the function is called
lambda x: self.clicked(row)

# New: x is the event, r is frozen when the function is created
lambda x, r=row: self.clicked(r)
```

This causes each lambda to have a local `r` set at creation-time rather than looking up `row` when the function is needed.

Comment: Thanks so much!! That did the trick, indeed creating a local copy of the `row` variable does exactly what I want.